# How to batch read files with specific strings in R?

Tags: r, loops

I have a folder containing multiple .tiff files with different years, model names and depths. For example, the filenames are:

> "tsl_CFmon_CESM2-WACCM_ssp245_r1i1p1f1_gn_2015_(0-0.022).tif"
>
> "tsl_CFmon_CESM2-WACCM_ssp245_r1i1p1f1_gn_2015_(0.022-0.08).tif"
>
> "tsl_CFmon_EC-Earth3_ssp245_r1i1p1f1_gn_2016_(0-0.022).tif"
>
> "tsl_CFmon_GFDL_ssp245_r1i1p1f1_gn_2016_(0.022-0.0.08).tif"
>
> etc.

The years are from 2015 to 2100. The model names are "CESM2-WACCM","EC-Earth3","GFDL",and so on. The content in parentheses indicates depths. I want to find all the files with the same model names in a certain year, for example "CESM2-WACCM" in 2015.
I tried this:

```
for(i in 2015:2100){
  myfiles <- list.files(pattern=paste0("CESM2-WACCM",i,".tif$"))
}
```

I also tried:

```
 myfiles <- Sys.glob("*CESM2-WACCM*i*.tif")
```

But they didn't work. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: if the currecnt working directory contains the files, just do `list.files(patters = 'CESM2-WACCM')` otherwise make use of the path parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just bring all the filenames back into a dataframe and then filter it from there.

```
files <- data.frame(filename=list.files(path="somefilepath", pattern="*.tif"))
```

Assuming this works then filter the dataframe as below:

```
library(tidyverse)
files<-files%>%
  mutate(filename2=sub(".tif", "", filename))%>%
  separate(filename2, sep = "_",into=as.character(c("col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6","col7","col8")) )%>%
  filter(col3=="CESM2-WACCM"& col7=="2015")
```

The filter is just an example, you can wrangle the data as you want.